# PHP, MySQL, Lost connection to MySQL server during query, TurnKey Ubuntu/Linux,

Tags: php, mysql, linux

Hi to all php and mysql experts,

I try to find some help or 'tutorial' or similar question/answer for my problem but it was unsuccessful. 
I have install TurnKey Linux, php, mysql, successfuly width ip address: 172.##.##.## and I can connect to this server from another comp. 
I was edit my my.cnf file, I was open port 3306 and I can connect via mysql -u root -p -h 172.##.##.## from another comp. I was add user:root that can connect from any host or IP address. Also I can make successful connections width mysqladmin or mysql workbench. 
I can, also, make database and some tables on this server like db_test, tab_test etc. and if I use next script on this server its work very good:

```
<?php
$db_hostname="localhost";
$db_username="root";
$db_password="pxxxxx";

    $db_connect=mysql_connect($db_hostname, $db_username, $db_password);
    if (!$db_connect) {
        die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    }

    mysql_close($db_connect);
?>
```

But if I use next script it does not work and report to me error: Could not connect: Lost connection to MySQL server during query;

```
<?php
$db_hostname="172.##.##.##";
$db_username="root";
$db_password="pxxxxx";

    $db_connect=mysql_connect($db_hostname, $db_username, $db_password);
    if (!$db_connect) {
        die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    }

    mysql_close($db_connect);
?>
```

Also this script it does not work if I use another php server witch can see or ping this server.

Can somebody help me to resolve this problem! Please. I am desperate.

Comment: might be a permission issue? i.e. can you check / post data in mysql.user : <<SELECT Host,User FROM mysql.user;>> if host <<172.16.4.238>> is not listed that might be your issue. In order to grant permissions you can use command <<GRANT SELECT ON [db].[table] TO 'user'@'172.16.4.238' WITH GRANT OPTION;>>. Hope this helps

Comment: ---- Thanks for your time! But I already said that **I was add user:root that can connect from any host or IP address**. The version of mysql that I use is: 5.1.63, Web Server: Apache/2.2.16 (Debian), Linux server: TurnKey 5.1.63-0+squeeze1.

Comment: have u tried with port no.

Comment: Check your php.ini on the separate server `mysql.connect_timeout` should be at least 60 possibly 120

Comment: Have you thought it might be blocked by a firewall?

Comment: Have you tried using `mysqli_connect`?

Comment: You said you are able to connect if you database  and code  are located at diffenent servers, Am I right?

Comment: Could we get the output of `SHOW GRANTS FOR CURRENT_USER();` ?

Comment: Thanks Folks, once again I will show you in details listed scenario:

Comment: 2nd: Yes, I can connect to my servers from different locations width: MySQL Workbench, when I am in same scope of IP address.

Comment: 3th: Yes, I am tried to use mysqli_coonect, but I got the same error.

Comment: 4th: I have no problems width firewalls. Everything goes right. I was open port 22, 80, 443, 3306 and etc... I can communicate width servers.

Comment: 5th: I was check php.ini and increase connect_timeout, also increase memory_limit.

Comment: 6th: For all who's interested in listed problem please look at this scenario carfully: Let us sign server 1 width PHP, MySQL and Apache server like Server1, server 2 widht PHP, MySQL and Apache like server2, and computer widht MySQL workbench like Comp1. Server1, Server2 and Comp1 are in the same IP scope. Each one can ping all other successfully. From Comp1 I can connect to Server1 and Server2 width MySQL Workbench and list tables from databases. ....

Comment: Next, I made some PHP applications that can store some data in database and retreive data from database. On both servers I use listed code width $db_hostname="localhost"; Everythings works fine.

Comment: But when I want to get data from Server1 to Server2 I use same here listed script width $db_hostname="172.##.##.##"; When I use that script I get the error: Lost connection to Mysql server during query.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same error, please go to xampp\phpMyAdmin\libraries\config.default.php

Modify the following code

```
existing one -  $cfg['ExecTimeLimit'] = 300;

modify to    -  $cfg['ExecTimeLimit'] = 600;
```

Comment: Hi, I do not use windows and your answer doesn't make sense because phpmyadmin has nothing to do width it.

Comment: on all computers is installed core Linux-Debian, without GUI.

Comment: and something else, these are not virtual machines.

Answer (score 0):

This is getting a bit long for a comment....

It doesn't appear to be a connection error - that's a different error message.

Changing the configuration of PHPMyAdmin is not going to make any difference to other scripts.

It might help if you publish details of the mysql config from PHP. Also is your mysqld started with [skip-name-resolve](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_skip-name-resolve)? How long does your example script take to fail?

One thing to watch for is that when the mysql client sees 'localhost' in the conection string, it tries to connect via a filesystem socket - not a network socket - do you get the same error when you supply the host as 172.##.##.## ?